# Buildbot: Is there a way to force all the builders to build?

Tags: buildbot

So, this is the problem: I have the buildbot set to build at 3 PM, altho when I work during the night, I am often in the situation where I need to trigger all my builders.

I am aware that I could use the buildmaster to make a fake commit and trigger the build, but what I am trying to achieve here is a "mass rebuild", like if I would go in each specific builder, select a build, and then push the "rebuild" button.

I can't figure out what that button is doing, just looking at the page code (I am no html expert), and in the documentation of the buildbot seems that there is no trace of how the standard pages that came with the buildbot are structured and operate.

I wish to add a button in the waterfall so I can just force all the builders (they are 26, you can imagine the effort to trigger them one by one).

Does anyone knows what is the command that is used by the "rebuild" button, and how can I take advantage of it to build all the builders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of builders page you have (or can configure) a "Force selected builds" and "Force All Builds" menus
If you don't have it you can configure it with

```
users = [(user, password)]
authz_cfg=authz.Authz(auth=BasicAuth(users),
    forceBuild = 'auth',
    forceAllBuilds = True,
    cancelPendingBuild = True,
    stopBuild = True,
    stopAllBuilds = True,
)
```

You can read more about Authz in the [documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.8/manual/cfg-statustargets.html)

Comment: That's why I didn't notice it...is called Authz; which to me sound like authorization...my brain excluded automatically that such section would contain anything related to the UI. Thanks!